# SQL queries in trigger statement

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm writing the code for an hotel management DB for school assignement.
i need to insert a query inside a trigger and my sql server gives me this sintaxerror:

> #1064 in the query SQL near 'SELECT codiceFiscale FROM IMPIEGATO WHERE ambiente=new.ambiente SET NEW.nome=U' line 5

CODE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS Gestione.ControlloExtra
BEFORE INSERT ON SPESEEXTRA
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    IF EXISTS SELECT codiceFiscale FROM IMPIEGATO WHERE ambiente=new.ambiente
        SET NEW.nome=UPPER(NEW.nome);
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (That code attempt is product specific, and won't run on both those products.)

Comment: Aren't you missing an END to your BEGIN?

Comment: I'm using MySQL.
Yes the END is missing but that is not the problem, the problem is the query.

Answer (score 2):

Subqueries need parentheses:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS Gestione.ControlloExtra
BEFORE INSERT ON SPESEEXTRA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT i.codiceFiscale FROM IMPIEGATO i WHERE i.ambiente = new.ambiente)
        SET NEW.nome = UPPER(NEW.nome);
    END IF;
    . . .
END;
```

Comment: @AlessandroSoffiati . . . It cannot be exactly the same error because of the parentheses.